# Coredata VFS flags - strange log

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, vfs

Since my latest update of Xcode, I get repeatedly the following log in my Coredata based app:

```
[logging] flag(s) 0x00000020 are reserved for VFS use and do not affect behaviour when passed to sqlite3_open_v2
```

Is this simply log noise or is it in any way relevant to me?

**Update:**
This happens under Xcode 13.2.1 on an iPhone with iOS 15.4. It does not happen on a Simulator with iOS 15.2.

Comment: Where is the app running when this happens? On an iOS device, or in the simulator? What version of iOS (or macOS for simulator)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is something you can ignore, that will probably be fixed when iOS 15.4 is out of beta.

According to the [SQLite file-open flag documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html),

- Flag value `0x00000020` is `SQLITE_OPEN_AUTOPROXY`, for what that's worth
- This flag is one of several flags that "...have historically been ignored by `sqlite3_open_v2()`", however...
- "...future versions of SQLite might change so that an error is raised if any of the disallowed bits are passed into `sqlite3_open_v2()`"

What this seems to say is that the flag has no effect and hasn't had one for a while, so it doesn't matter if Core Data is using it internally. The message probably means that iOS 15.4 has a newer version of SQLite which has started to print warnings about it but hasn't started causing errors yet.

I'd expect this to be fixed when 15.4 is released, and in the meantime I encourage you to [file a bug with Apple](http://feedbackassistant.apple.com) just in case.